# Wait until user responds to onscreen view and then execute code

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, swift3, synchronized

So there may already be a question like this, but I was not able to find a similar one.

Pretty much what I'm trying to do, is the user is going to receive some invite from another device. Then there is going to be a view that will pop up over the current view asking the user to accept or decline the invitation.

If the user accepts the invitation I need to perform an action, however, I can't seem to get the thread to wait until the user responds and I'm not sure the best course of action.

I've been reading into GCD to see if I'm able to come up with a solution from there, but I've never used GCD before and I wasn't able to figure it out.

Here is my code which is within a method:

```
        DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: {

            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                print("\(#file) > \(#function) > In new thread: \(Thread.current)")

                let popOverView = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IncomingCall") as! IncomingCallViewController
                self.addChildViewController(popOverView)

                popOverView.peerIndex = self.getIndexForPeer(peer: fromPeer)
                popOverView.messages = self.messages

                popOverView.view.frame = self.view.frame
                self.view.addSubview(popOverView.view)
                popOverView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

                print("\(#file) > \(#function) > Finished synchronized code on thread: \(Thread.current)")
            }

            print("\(#file) > \(#function) > \(Thread.current))")
            // Need to execute some code HERE when the user responds
        })
```

What I was hoping was that the thread that runs the code within: DispatchQueue.main.sync would continue to run when the new popOver moved to the parent. But this is not the case, and as soon as the popOverView is pushed to the screen then the final print statement runs.

Does anyone know the best course of action here?

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't be using GCD for this at all. What you could do is call a closure on the PopOver triggered by the user tapping a UIButton on the PopOver. In that closure you would perform your action.

Comment: @mattsson Hmmm.. Okay, I'll have to look up closures, I've never used them before. I should also note that when the user clicks the Accept button the PopOverView disappears, and then we need to perform a segue to another view. Does this change anything?

Comment: Well, you don't have to use a closure. It would maybe make more sense to just set a target and selector, i.e. a method, which will be triggered when the UIButton is tapped (`addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`). It's okay that the view is disappearing as long as you set another view as the target of the UIButton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do *not* use threads and *do not "wait"*. Never never never "wait". iOS programming is *event-driven*. Your job is to *organize* your code to be called in response to appropriate / desired events.

> If the user accepts the invitation I need to perform an action

Then respond to the user tapping the Accept button by performing that action. It's as simple as that.

That, after all, is how a UIAlertController's view behaves. No code pauses or "waits" just because the alert is up. Your code *responds* to the user event, i.e. the user taps a button in the alert.

Comment: But can I call a method from another view when the user clicks a button? And in my case when the button is clicked, I need to go back to the previous view and then segue to a different view, is this also possible?

Comment: Sure, all of that is possible.